# Blur Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, blur

Help . I can not be import project .

> Error:(16, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Could
>   not find method runProguard() for arguments [false] on
>   BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false,
>   testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false,
>   pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false,
>   renderscriptOptimLevel=3, versionNameSuffix=null, minifyEnabled=false,
>   zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true,
>   mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[],
>   mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.

Answer (score 0):

check you build.gradle file configuration for `buildTypes`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```